# how to get Previous Day?

Tags: javascript

I have date object:

```
dateObj = new Date(year, month, date[, hours, minutes, seconds, ms] )
```

How to get dateObj - 1 day ?

Answer (score 71):

```
dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()-1);
```

Comment: +1 @Bdfy: "date" is the JavaScript `Date` object term for "day of month." Subtracting one from it works, even on the 1st of the month, because the JavaScript `Date` object is smart about it.

Comment: i just get a bunch of integers

Answer (score 6):

By subtracting one day (1000 ms * 60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours):

```
new Date(+new Date(year, month, date[, hours, minutes, seconds, ms] ) - 1000*60*60*24);
```

Comment: The `getTime()` should be called implicitly when doing arithmetic operators :)

Comment: Problematic if the day in question doesn't have 24 hours. Happens twice a year in most timezones...

Comment: @T.J. - So how do I accurately represent 1:30am on a day when the clock is being set back since there are 2 1:30am's?

Comment: @TJ - apparently it's not problematic as JS doesn't seem to recognize timezone changes: `new Date(+new Date('11/06/2011 00:00:00 GMT')+1000*60*60*24)`  I can never get it to skip/subtract a hour due to daylight savings (11/06/2011 is the next daylight savings day.  Also tried 6 months to be sure)

Comment: @cwolves: The clocks in the UK don't change on 11/06/2011 (that "GMT" in your string is important, it tells JavaScript what timezone to apply -- we Brits being a bit schizo and calling our standard time "GMT"). If you use 27/03/2011, you'll see the effect: http://jsbin.com/uvubu3/2 That shows that midnight on 27/03/2011 plus 24 hours is 1 a.m. on 28/03/2011, because the 27th only has 23 hours. Whereas with `setDate`, it stays midnight. Now, which you want to use will depend on what you're doing, but when I think "add a day" I'm usually thinking in terms of "without affecting the time of day."

Comment: @TJ - I'm not seeing that same behavior...  No matter what, +24 hours == same time for me

Comment: @cwolves: *"So how do I accurately represent 1:30am on a day when the clock is being set back...?"* With a timezone. (Fun, isn't it?) Example: http://jsbin.com/uvubu3/3 There are two different time values for 1:30 a.m. on 30/10/2011, one for BST (British Summer Time), and one for GMT (an hour later). :-)

Comment: @cwolves: *"I'm not seeing that same behavior..."* You're not seeing it with my link? That's weird! What browser are you using? I've tried Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE7... Let me try a different timezone (e.g., one I'm not actually in).

Comment: @TJ - I just tested a script by adding 1 hour to a date object 100,000 times... I ___always___ get a string that is exactly +1 hour of the previous one.  Perhaps it's a localization setting??  FF & Chrome.  FYI, I'm in PST (West-Coast USA)

Comment: @cwolves: Just to be sure, again, you don't see it with my http://jsbin.com/uvubu3/2 link? What timezone gets displayed? Also, I'm curious what you see with this: http://jsbin.com/uvubu3/4 (This is interesting, hopefully for you too; I s'pose we should probably take it offline and just post back the outcome, but...)

Comment: @TJ: `Sat Oct 29 2011 17:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)` ... `Sat Oct 29 2011 18:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Comment: @cwolves: Okay, that explains why you're not seeing it there, your local timezone is applied (and of course, your clocks don't change that day). What about http://jsbin.com/uvubu3/4? (Thanks for exploring this with me, btw.)

Comment: @TJ - Great, that one shows `1:30am PST (-8)` then `1:30am PDT (-7)`.   I guess I wasn't applying the time-zones to it as I was getting `GMT` as my result which, of course, wouldn't ever show a change (slaps forehead)

Answer (score 1):

Some useful functions that doesnt mutate the orignal date object:

```js
function prevDate(date) {
  let copy = new Date(date.valueOf());
  return new Date(copy.setDate(copy.getDate() - 1));
}

function nextDate(date) {
  let copy = new Date(date.valueOf());
  return new Date(copy.setDate(copy.getDate() + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the moment.js library https://momentjs.com/docs/

To get the date previous day you would simply need to do...

```
moment().add(-1, 'days');
```