# how to compare date in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i have this type of code condition

```
stopped_at: {
        $lte: new Date(Date.now() - 86400 * 1000)
    }
```

This works for getting date that is <= 24 hour
but is there any easy solution than this?

i want date that is <=24 hour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get Previous Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960674/how-to-get-previous-day)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another implementation , which gives exact one day before current day.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var oneDayBefore = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
oneDayBefore.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the moment.js library. Very useful when working with dates!

https://momentjs.com/docs/

To get the date 24 hours before the current date you would simply need to do...

```
moment().add(-1, 'days');
```